# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'county_id' cannot be null

Tags: laravel-8

I am trying to save my data from a dynamic selected dropdown into my database but I'm having errors doing so.

This is the error I am getting.

`` SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'county_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `properties` (`National_id`, `Plot_No`, `Property_Ad`, `Property_Photo`, `Property_features`, `county_id`, `sc_id`, `town_id`, `type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (63636, 424545, Duplex Apartments, test.jpg, Free parking, ?, ?, ?, ?, 2023-02-18 09:42:30, 2023-02-18 09:42:30)) ``

I need help on how to save a selected drop down to a database which is a foreign key referencing another table (county_id references id on the county table, sc_id references id on the subcounty table and town_id references id on the town table).

This is my livewire page.

```
<form id="add-property-form" method="POST" action="{{URL::to('saveProperty')}}">
    @csrf
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                        @if ($errors->any())
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li class="text-white">{{ $error }}</li>
                                     @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                <div class= "form-group">
            <!--input pattern= "[a-zA-Z]{2,10}$" required-->
            <p>National id</p><input type="number"   required name="National_id" value="{{old('National_id')}}"  class="form-control @error('National_id') is-invalid @enderror"
             placeholder="Confirm your National id number"> 
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    @error('National_id') {{$message}} @enderror
                </div>

            <p>Plot No</p><input type="number"   required name="plot_no" value="{{old('plot_no')}}"  class="form-control @error('plot_no') is-invalid @enderror"
             placeholder="Please enter plot number"> 
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    @error('plot_no') {{$message}} @enderror
                </div>

             <p>Property Description</p><input type="text"   required name="Property_Ad" value="{{old('Property_Ad')}}"  class="form-control @error('Property_Ad') is-invalid @enderror"
             placeholder="Please enter property description">
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    @error('Property_Ad') {{$message}} @enderror
                </div>

             <p>Property Features</p><input type="text"   required name="Property features" value="{{old('Property_features')}}"  class="form-control @error('Property_features') is-invalid @enderror"
             placeholder="Please enter property features">
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    @error('Property_features') {{$message}} @enderror
                </div>

             <p>Property Images</p><input type="file" required name="Property_Photo" value="{{old('Property_Photo')}}"  class="form-control"
             >

             <p>Location</p>

             <div class="row align-items-start">
<div class="col">
<select id="County" class="form-select-lg mb-3 form-control" wire:model = "selectedCounty" name="County">
  <option value="" >County</option>
      @foreach ($counties as $co)
      <option value="{{$co->id}}">{{$co->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>
</div>


@if (!is_null($subcounty))
<div class="col">
<select id="subCounty" class="form-select-lg mb-3 form-control" wire:model = "selectedSubCounty" name="subCounty">
  <option value="">SubCounty</option>
    @foreach ($subcounty as $su)
      <option value="{{$su->id}}">{{$su->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
</div>
@endif


@if (!is_null($town))
<div class="col">
<select id="Town" class="form-select-lg mb-3 form-control" wire:model = "selectedTown" name="Town">
  <option value="">Town</option>
    @foreach ($town as $to)
      <option value="{{$to->id}}">{{$to->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
</div>
@endif
  </div>


             <p>Property Type</p><input type="text"   required name="property_type" value="{{old('type')}}" title="2-10 characters"  class="form-control @error('type') is-invalid @enderror"
             placeholder="Please enter your property type">
                 <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    @error('type') {{$message}} @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success" >

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</form>
```

This is my view page

```
@extends('layout')

@section('headTitle', 'Your Properties / Add Property')

@section('pageTitle', 'Your Properties / Add Property')

@section('content')

<livewire:subcounty />

@endsection
```

This is my controller page.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\home_owners;
use App\Models\property;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ProController extends Controller
{
    public function viewProperties(){
        $allPros = property::paginate(7);
        //dd is the laravel version of var_dump() & die();
        //dd($allRoles);
             return view('HO.properties', ['properties'=>$allPros]);
    }

    public function addProperty(){
        return view('HO.addproperty');
    }

    public function saveProperty(Request $request){

            $prop = new property();
            $prop->National_id=$request->National_id;
            $prop->Plot_No=$request->plot_no;
            $prop->Property_Ad=$request->Property_Ad;
            $prop->Property_Photo=$request->Property_Photo;
            $prop->Property_features=$request->Property_features;
            $prop->county_id=$request->county_id;
            $prop->sc_id=$request->sc_id;
            $prop->town_id=$request->town_id;
            $prop->type=$request->type;

            if($request->hasFile('Property_photo')){

                $file = $request->file('Property_photo');
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $filename = time().'.'.$extension;
                $file->move('uploads/properties', $filename);
                $prop->Property_Photo = $filename;
            
            
            
            }
            $prop->save();
            return redirect('properties')->with('status',"New Property added.");
    }



    public function editProperty(){

    }
}
```

Comment: I am pretty new to laravel, but did you **debug**, and take a look at the value of `$request->Country` ?

Comment: Where exactly..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically it is indicating that the `county_id` field is being sent `empty` or `null` to the database, in your form the `county_id` field is called `County`, you need to change it:

`<select id="County" class="form-select-lg mb-3 form-control" wire:model = "selectedCounty" name="County">`

to

`<select id="County" class="form-select-lg mb-3 form-control" wire:model = "selectedCounty" name="county_id">`